# Lead Converted Status Not Appearing

Tags: lead-conversion, configuration, sales-process

Am I missing some sort of setting here? I know for a fact the 'Converted Status' on the Lead Process dictates the available Lead Statuses when converting a lead, and obviously SFDC's [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=leads_convert.htm&language=en_US) backs that up.

> In the Converted Status picklist, select a status for the converted lead. Choices include statuses marked as “converted” by your administrator.

I have 'Identified' selected as the converted value for the 'Enterprise' Lead Process.
[image]

I have the 'Enterprise' Lead Process assigned to the 'Company' record type.[image]

All of the correct values appear on the record when that record type is selected, but when I get to the actual conversion screen, I only see a Converted Lead Status of 'Sold' which is for a different Lead Process we have in place.

Why can't I see the available converted status for this record type/lead process?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be related to the default record type. When logged in with a user that has the Record Type with 'Enterprise' process assigned as the default, I see 'Identified' as the conversion status.

There is a setting under Lead Settings: App Setup > Customize > Leads > Settings.

This setting says "Do not change lead status values to new owner's record type on lead conversion". Marking that TRUE will allow any user to set the conversion status for the lead process assigned to any record type.

Further, I found the [metadata for Lead Settings](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_unsupported_types.htm) is not supported, so you cannot deploy that setting from one environment to another.